# Time and Space Complexity Practice (for using array length property)

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have an array

```
int[] array = new int[10]{...}
```

I need to use this array length in different places inside my program.

Is it good practice to get it in variable like

```
int n = array.Length
```

and use the variable `n` everywhere?
Or I can simply use

```
array.Length
```

everywhere it is needed.. since it is simple one , not a big calculation ?

Is there any significant difference in terms of time and space taken between these two approach?

Comment: If you are concerned with performance, then you should test, test and test yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Accessing `Array.Length` will *probably* be **as efficient** as keeping a separate variable, and therefore it is **not** advisable as a general guideline.

**Longer Answer:**

As you can see in the [**`Array.Length`** Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.6), in the remarks section:

> Retrieving the value of this property is an **O(1)** operation.

*(emphasis is mine)*.

This means that when you call `Array.Length` there is no need to traverse the array and count the elements (which would be an **O(n)** operation).

Instead the array class is keeping track of the number of elements in an internal member or property, which is returned when you access `Array.Length`.

Therefore is it **very likely** that keeping a separate variable will perform very similarly to accessing `Array.Length` (the only difference is the need to reference the array instance, but I tend to believe it is negligable).

**However** - if you are concerned about performance issues and suspect it is a critical area - the only real answer is that you have to measure both options and find out.

Comment: There is an extra level of pointer indirection though, but that's unlikely to make a measurable difference

Comment: Do you mean accessing the `this` pointer ? If so I assume it is negligable.

Comment: No, accessing the array reference, for example `array.Length` has to de-reference `array` first, whereas a direct field would not. Yes it's negligible, that's what I said. It's also likely to be inlined in tight loops anyway, due to loop invariant hoisting.

Comment: @Charlieface this is what I meant by the `this` pointer (the `this` pointer of the array instance). Although I think it is negligable, I added a note to my answer that it should be measured to make sure.

Comment: _"the only real answer is that you have to measure both options and find out"_. The answer you've provided is just re-stating existent information. Add a few performance benchmarks, for the sake of completeness

Comment: @AbhinavMathur My asnwer was attempting to give a general advise based on my intuition, with some explanations how I got to this conclusion. But as with other performance critical issues intuitions are not enough and measurements should be done by the OP in his specific system etc. In most implementations accessing array length will not be of critical performance and in those cases it is not required to perform benchmarks, because of the explanation I gave about the complexity of the property.